# banner refresh code

Tags: javascript

I have banner code, which is not like images and hyperlinks. All I need is the javascript code that will refresh this code every 30 seconds without refreshing the rest of the page.

This banner code will be appear in chatroom. I would really appreciate any help. 
The banner code:

```
<script language='JavaScript' 
        type='text/javascript' 
        src='xxxxxx/banner.php?uname=yyyy&type=2&rows=1' >    
</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post the actual code involved, or something ...

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is wrap your code in a function. Trying to re-invoke an entire scripting file import is much more difficult than just invoking a function.

Once everything is wrapped in a function, you can use setTimeout to invoke the method. I would do something like this:

```
function drawBanner() {
    // Do stuff to draw the banner.
    // Make sure you handle the case that the
    // banner is already present in the DOM!
}

function onDrawBannerTimer() {
    // Set this function to fire again after 30 seconds.
    // Note that this will fire it roughly every 30 seconds real-time.
    // You can move this statement to after the drawBanner() call
    // in order to make it 30 seconds between the end of one
    // invocation and the start of the next.
    setTimeout(onDrawBannerTimer, 30 * 1000);
    drawBanner();
}

// Trigger the first invocation when the script is loaded.
onDrawBannerTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to give that script tag an ID (such as `id='dynScript'`) and then have another script block that does pretty much the following: [Note: I'm using jQuery]

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout ( $('#dynScript').attr('src','xxxxxx/banner.php?uname=yyyy&type=2&rows=1'), 3000);
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: is code so corect ? if yes not work, sorry i am beginne please explain me how do i set this code <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout ( $('#dynScript').attr

('src','h t t p://xxxxx/banner.php?

uname=xxx&type=2&rows=1'), 3000);
  }); 
</script>